# Why can I only implement Equatable in an extension

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to define a test fixture that conforms to `Equatable` so that I can verify a function that takes a protocol performs as expected. I've tried 3 different permutations.

```
import XCTest
import MyProtocol

struct TestFixture {
    let identifier: String
    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
}

extension TestFixture: MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolFunc() {}
}

extension TestFixture: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: TestFixture, rhs: TestFixture) {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }
}

class TestCase: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() {
        // do something that requires a MyProtocol object
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, I would like to convert `TestFixture` into a nested definition, so I try this:

```
import XCTest
import MyProtocol

class TestCase: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() {

        struct TestFixture {
            let identifier: String
            init(identifier: String) {
                self.identifier = identifier
            }
        }

        extension TestFixture: MyProtocol {
            func myProtocolFunc() {}
        }

        extension TestFixture: Equatable {
            static func ==(lhs: TestFixture, rhs: TestFixture) {
                return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
            }
        }

        // do something that requires a MyProtocol object
    }
}
```

At this point I get a compiler error on both of the `extension` declarations:

> Declaration is only valid at file scope

Ok, so I guess I'm not supposed to implement extensions on nested definitions. So I'll just implement all the protocols on the initial declaration:

```
import XCTest
import MyProtocol

class TestCase: XCTestCase {
    func testSomething() {

        struct TestFixture: MyProtocol, Equatable {
            let identifier: String
            init(identifier: String) {
                self.identifier = identifier
            }

            func myProtocolFunc() {}

            static func ==(lhs: TestFixture, rhs: TestFixture) {
                return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
            }
        }

        // do something that requires a MyProtocol object
    }
}
```

And now I get the compiler error

> Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

So my question is: why does the compiler only complain about `Equatable` having associated type requirements when I implement it in the initial declaration of a struct? And why can't I define extensions in nested types? I just want to understand *why* the compiler is doing these things.

---

To provide a bit more context, what I'm trying to test here is that a class correctly appends a `MyProtocol` object to an array:

```
class MyClass {
    var elements: [MyProtocol] {
        return _elements
    }
    private var _elements: [MyProtocol] = []
    func add(_ element: MyProtocol) {
        // I'm testing this function
    }
}
```

Comment: _"... why does the compiler only complain about `Equatable` having associated type requirements when I implement it in the initial declaration of a struct?"_: there's no issue implementing conformance to `Equatable` in the initial declaration of some struct. The issue here seems to stem from the fact that this type is declared _within the scope of a function_ (which I, tbh, didn't know was even legal). Note that there is no issue if you just use nested types (but leave out declaring them in a function scope).

Comment: @dfri thanks, it seems you're right. If I move the declaration out of the function scope and into the class scope it compiles fine. I've been using the in-function class definitions for the test fixtures because it's quite useful for this purpose, but I must be pushing the compiler a bit too far.

Comment: Tbh, this behaviour seems kind of buggy: we cannot conform to any kind of homogeneous protocol (`Self` or associated type requirements) if we place a type declaration within a function, whereas conformance to homogeneous protocols work fine. This seems ambiguous as I believe, imho, that we should either not be able to declare type within functions blocks _at all_, or, be able to declare types just as in other blocks, including types that conform to a homogen. protocol as specified at the type's declaration. Possibly worth filing a bug report, unless someone else can explain this discrepancy.

Comment: Agreed. I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the Swift compiler. The current solution is to declare the struct outside of the function scope.

An issue has been opened: [SR-3092](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3092).